# Line break at the first comma by 40 characters

Tags: jquery, join, replace

I want to replace every comma after 40 characters with a line break.

So if the script passed the 40 characters than a line break at the first comma.

From:

```
43 characters, 46 characters, 41 characters,
```

To:

```
 43 characters,
 46 characters,
 41 characters,
```

An example, string:

```
  FFS Level D Secondary Control, A320 and A330 for Trim Wheel, B737 for Throttles, Nose Wheel Tiller, Speed Brake Handle, FTD, Secondary Control.
```

To:
`FFS Level D Secondary Control, A320 and A330 for Trim Wheel,
 B737 for Throttles, Nose Wheel Tiller, 
Speed Brake Handle, FTD, Secondary Control.`

My current code:
`application_json.match(/.{1,40}/g).join("<br/>");`

Comment: Why the break after `Control,`? It's less than 40 characters

Comment: @Toto Sorry my bad, I will edit the question!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var oldStr = 'FFS Level D Secondary Control, A320 and A330 for Trim Wheel, B737 for Throttles, Nose Wheel Tiller, Speed Brake Handle, FTD, Secondary Control.';
var charCount = 0;
var newStr = '';
for (var i = 0, len = oldStr.length; i < len; i++)
{
    newStr += oldStr.charAt(i);
    charCount++;
    if (oldStr.charAt(i) == ',' && charCount >= 40) {
        newStr += '<br />';
        charCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Read every character (incrementing also a counter) and when the counter exceeds 40 and the current character is a comma, add a line break and make the counter zero again for the next pass.

EDIT: If you need the comma to be **after** at least 40 characters and not be accidentally part of these 40 characters, replace `charCount >= 40` with `charCount > 40`

Comment: If you need the comma to be ***after*** at least 40 characters and not be accidentally part of these 40 characters, replace `charCount >= 40` with `charCount > 40`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using indexof that I wrote earlier but didn't get a chance to post.

It uses `indexOf` starting at current position (s) +40 (so next comma after minimum of 40 chars)

```js
var source = "FFS Level D Secondary Control, A320 and A330 for Trim Wheel, B737 for Throttles, Nose Wheel Tiller, Speed Brake Handle, FTD, Secondary Control."

var result = "";
var s = 0;
var e = source.indexOf(",", s + 40) + 1;
// >=1 rather than !=-1 as indexOf uses +1 to include the comma
while (e >= 1 && s < source.length) {
  result = result + source.substring(s, e) + "\n";
  s = e;
  e = source.indexOf(",", s + 40) + 1;
}
result = result + source.substring(s);
console.log(result)
```

I also had a go at a reg ex version and got this:

```js
var source = "FFS Level D Secondary Control, A320 and A330 for Trim Wheel, B737 for Throttles, Nose Wheel Tiller, Speed Brake Handle, FTD, Secondary Control."

var r2 = source.match(/.{40}.*?,|.*$/g).join("\n");
console.log(r2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! especially the regex one!!